# The Orville - You'll Never Walk Alone identification

Tags: music, music-identification, the-orville

In Season 3, Episode 5 of *The Orville* the closing scene shows

> Topa as she walks onto the bridge,

and an orchestral version of "You'll Never Walk Alone" plays. What is the performing group and/or album this is from, if it wasn't a special recording for the episode? I haven't been able to find any track on the internet that has the structure where the melody is passed between sections (in the episode, it starts in the cellos, then moves to woodwinds, then on to higher strings). A good answer will list a track that contains a portion very similar or identical in structure and instrumentation to the clip in the episode, and a great answer will cite an authoritative source referencing the source of the track.

Comment: The official soundtrack album's not been released yet. Does this count as future works? Or possibly trivia? I ask for confirmation.

Comment: Also, if you're wishing for music identification, is that on-topic anyhow? It would certainly be helpful if you provided a sample to compare. [Tried this one?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44vAH8c23Eo), Cello, but piano/synth, not woodwind.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. - We don't screen for trivia. It's not one of our close reasons. And yes, a music-ID question from a sci-fi series would be firmly on-topic here.

Comment: @cat40 - the show has its own musical team. I'd imagine that they arranged and recorded it themselves rather than buying in a track from elsewhere

Comment: Have you tried feeding it to Shazam?

Comment: I tried it on Shazam.  No result found.  Here is the clip https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeBCRHL3c-k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an original scoring by the show's musical director, Andrew Cottee.  You can see him conducting the 75-piece 'Dream Town Orchestra' in the Instagram post below with the caption *"[Andrew Cottee @dreamtownmusic1 conducting his first score of the season for #TheOrville New Horizons!](https://www.instagram.com/p/CXkcD81jo1D/)"*

[image]

Seth McFarlane also posted the complete cue [on his Instagram feed](https://www.instagram.com/p/Cfk8xQxjfnt/) a few days ago.

Comment: Wow! That's an amazing find I never would have come across myself (being as it is that I don't use Instagram very often). It's such a beautiful piece of music and I hope it gets released if a soundtrack ever comes out